# Problem with Workflow Designer

Tags: .net, xaml, workflow, workflow-foundation

When I open a xamlx file the designer shows this:

[image]

I am having trouble fixing this. Here's the xaml:

```
<WorkflowService mc:Ignorable="sap" ConfigurationName="ExemptPAService" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="516,1183" Type="Exempt"
                 mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the end of Line 0, you'll find `Type="Exempt"`. The exception, rightfully, notifies you that `Type` is not a property or dependency property on `WorkflowService`.

Comment: Just figured that out on my own, but thanks anyway. What I don't get is how that got there if it's not supposed to be.

Comment: I've experienced many odd "phantom" properties in my trials with the WF designer, and I think it is due to design time confusion of dependency properties. I've yet to nail it down though.

Comment: Good thing to watch out for. Thanks.